# Are uncorrelated linear combinations of the elements of a multivariate normal distribution always independent of each other?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, correlation, variance, bivariate-distributions

To make a simple example, we could have $X \sim N_2 \left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -4 \\ -4 & 2\end{pmatrix} \right)$ which gives $X_1 \sim N(0, 4)$ and $X_2 \sim N (0,2)$. Does this give us that $X_1$ is Independent of $X_1+X_2$?

NB: $\text{Cov}(X_1, X_1+X_2) = \text{Var}(X_1) + \text{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = 4 - 4 = 0$, so these two linear combinations are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: linear transforms of multivariate normal random variables are again multivariate normal, and uncorrelated implies independent for multivariate normal random variables.

Comment: I'd agree that all non-trivial linear combinations of the elements of a multivariate normal distribution are univariate normal, but how does this extend to the overarching multivariate distribution?

Comment: The property of being (multivariate) normal is preserved by linear transformations.  See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation).  Two linear combinations constitutes a linear map into $\mathbb R^2$, and so the two linear combinations are jointly normal.